# get bigger bitmap from view than getDrawingCache() can do

Tags: android, view, bitmap, screenshot

I have a `RelativeLayout` and I want to save its content to `Bitmap`. There are tonns of solutions here but no one suits for my task.
The main difficult is that view has, lets say, 700x900 px size. I want to get a screenshot of that view as the size would be 1000x1000. I cannot just make a screenshot with `getDrawingCache()` and scale it because views inside `RelativeLayout` will be shrinked/stretched.
I think that I need to resize view itself, make a Bitmap from it, and resize it back. But! If I resize a view it will be bigger than screen and `getDrawingCache()` works only for visible part of the view. I cannot put my into ScrollView to workaround such behaviour.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: save content to bitmap means you want to take screenshot in the your relative layout ??

Comment: `View#draw()` does not work?

Comment: @AalapPatel yep

Comment: @pskink Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            content.layout(0, 0, width, height);
            content.draw(c);

does not work. image has correct sizes but it contains only visible part of the view, not the whole one

Comment: so the rest is black or what? does `content` have a parent view?

Comment: @pskink it's transparent. yes, it has a parent view

Comment: @pskink here is an example of the image generated with the code i posted before in the comments: https://imgur.com/a/q8Xd5